# grep particular string from multiple lines

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

i have file which contain the information of many users. 
for example .

```
Name: firstname:jessica middlename:albert lastname:peters
phone: 872634823468
Mobile: 72364623646
Address: Apacrtment : CT APT , Road : MG Road , City : Mumbai
Job : Software developer.

Name: firstname:ram middlename:kishan lastname:pichai
phone: 3242342342
Mobile: 12343545435
Address: Apacrtment : Antop APT , Road : AT Road , City : Delhi
Job : Senior developer.
```

I want to grep particular value from particular lines . 
i am able to find the lines with egrep command .

for example

```
 egrep "Name|Mobile|Address" test.log
    Name: jessica albert peters
    Mobile: 72364623646
    Address: Apartment : CT APT , Road : MG Road , City : Mumbai
```

how can i find out out particular string from above lines and save them in comma separated value . 
for example i am looking output like

```
expected output
Name,Mobile,City
jessica,72364623646,Mumbai
ram,12343545435,Delhi
```

Comment: Good that you have showed your efforts which you have put to solve this problem, request you NOT to post real data on forums, I am seeing mobile numbers are there in post, kindly always put dummy data.

Answer (score 1):

If your actual Input_file is same as shown samples then following may help you here.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
  print "Name,Mobile,City"
}
/^Name:/{
  sub(/.*:/,"",$2)
  val=$2
  next
}
/^Mobile/{
  val=val OFS $2
  next
}
/City/{
  match($0,/City : .*/)
  print val OFS substr($0,RSTART+7,RLENGTH-7)
  val=""
}'   Input_file
```

Comment: you make the most difficult awk's possible, it cause of your answer's i begin to use this command so well

Comment: @Inder, thanks man glad to hear that I could help you, happy learning.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk` with an empty `RS`:

```
awk -v OFS=, -F ' *[,:] *|[[:space:]]+' -v RS= 'BEGIN{print "Name", "Mobile", "City"}
{print $3, $11, $20}' file
```

```
Name,Mobile,City
jessica,72364623646,Mumbai
ram,12343545435,Delhi
```

Comment: Many Many congratulations for achieving 500K, you are too good sir, hats off to you. I really want to become like you 1 day.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that file follow this pattern that you showed

The following commands help you to catch:

Name: `cat teste.txt | grep -e "Name" | awk -F" " '{ print $2 }' | awk -F":" '{ print $2 }'`

Mobile: `cat teste.txt | grep -e "Mobile" | awk -F " " '{ print $2 }'`

Address: `cat teste.txt | grep -e "Address" | awk -F"City : " '{ print $2 }'`

After this just use a foreach loop to write in a csv file

Comment: y not use a single line awk like the other answers suggest, don't you think this wil be a slower approach ???

Comment: Yes, and the `grep` is also [useless.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)